# Determining whether the event is independent

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A fair coin is tossed five times repeatedly. Let $A$ be the event in which the number of heads that appeared is at least 2 and $B$ the event in which the number of tails that appeared is at least 2.

Find whether the events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

So far I took $p$ as the probability of heads appearing in a single toss. Then $p= 0.5$. Since this is tossed 5 times(i.e. $n=5$)

\begin{align}P(A)=P(H\geq 2)&=1-[P(H=0)+P(H=1)]\\
&=1-\Big[\binom{5}{0}\cdot 0.5^5 + \binom{5}{1} \cdot 0.5\cdot0.5^4\Big]\\
&= 0.8126
\end{align} 
In the same manner $P(B)$ can be derived as $0.8126$

To show those events are independent how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: What is the event $A\cap B$? You start with $A=\lbrace H=2\rbrace\cup\ldots\cup \lbrace H=5\rbrace$ and similar for $B$! Note that $\lbrace H=2\rbrace$ is the same as $\lbrace T=3\rbrace$

Comment: Yes, If I can show $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)*P(B)$$  then it is independent.
To calculate$$A\cap B$$ do I need to take events  2H3T and 3H2T right?

Comment: @emil You´re right.